# What is Omer and how much is it?

Tags: shiurim-measurements

My understanding is that Omer is a handfuls, which is about 1 US Cup or 236g. This is exact amount needed to produce bread for one day for one healthy adult.

What do traditional sources say an Omer is in modern measurements?

Comment: IIRC, there is an online resource that converts almost all Biblical measurements to current metric and / or U.S. measurements. They include length, volume and time among others, I believe. If you're interested, infrom me. I'll have to dig it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rabbi A.H. Noeh](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Chaim_Naeh) says it's about 5.2 pints, or about 2.5 liters. [The Chazon Ish](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yeshaya_Karelitz) says it's about 1.75 times that.

Source: *Aiding Talmud Study*, by [Rabbi Aryeh Carmell](/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Carmell) (ISBN 0-87306-428-3), page 78.

Comment: Followup question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67350

Answer (score 3):

My husband and I did extensive research on the hin, omer, and ephah, and correlated all the constraints on the omer from the Bible texts, including recipes for the daily grain offerings, recipes for the showbread, daily caloric intake, average size of barley grains, average size of fingerwidth, measurements of the table of showbread, and sizes of the loaves by Josephus, and more.  Here is a link to the research.  http://readyanswers.org/PathfinderBibleExperience/Exodus/ConstraintsHinOmerEphah.pdf

The best guess recreation of the omer is 3.4 US Cups, or about 1 US quart.

Comment: Fascinating research you've done. Kudos.

Comment: @Shelley_Houser, since you all have studied the word omer extensively, can you tell why, even Jewish translators, have translated the Hebrew word "omer" with the English word "sheaf", which would be misleading, isn't it, when "omer" means a "measure" (that is, as in your research, a measure equivalent to 3.4 US Cups)?